# Indy SaveToFile vs SaveToStream and BCC

Tags: delphi, stream, c++builder, indy

I understand Indy developers have chosen to strip BCC headers of the message when using `SaveToStream` because stream can be socket-based. But what if I want to actually save the message into the stream for further processing? Furthermore, what if I wanted to strip the CRLF.CRLF added after the end? The example of this would be saving a message to MBOX-type file. This of course cannot be done directly.

So my approach right now is a real mess:

```c++
// Writing to MBOX
// Save to temp file
IdMsg->SaveToFile("filenamewrite.tmp",false);

// Make file shorter by 5 trailing bytes
boost::scoped_ptr<TFileStream> fs(new TFileStream("filenamewrite.tmp", fmOpenWrite | fmShareDenyWrite));
fs->Size = fs->Size-5;
FlushFileBuffers(reinterpret_cast<void *>(fs->Handle));

// Now this file can be copied to another stream with "mbox"-like file.
```

And for the loading:

```c++
// Reading from MBOX
boost::scoped_ptr<TFileStream> fs(new TFileStream("mboxfile", fmOpenRead | fmShareDenyWrite));
AnsiString Data;
Data.SetLength(12345);
fs->Read(const_cast<void *>(Data.data()), Data.Length());
boost::scoped_ptr<TStringList> sl(new TStringList);
sl->Text = Data;
sl->SaveToFile("filenameread.tmp");
IdMsg->LoadFromFile("filenameread.tmp");
```

Of course, this is terribly unefficient way of doing this and completely unnecessary. If it would be possible to save directly to stream it would be 2 lines of code instead of above mess.

Is there a better way? How about adding an overloaded `SaveToStream` to allow removing CRLF.CRLF and saving BCC header in Indy? And similar for `LoadFromStream` when message is loaded from MBOX so it can be loaded directly from stream without the need to add trailing CRLF.CRLF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TIdMessage` writes the `BCC` header only when `TIdMessage.SaveToFile()` is called.  There is no way to make `TIdMessage.SaveToStream()` write the `BCC` header without altering Indy's source code or using a hack class.  You can, however, manually store the `BCC` data in the `TIdMessage.ExtraHeaders` property so `SaveToStream()` can then write it.

As for handling the extra dots and such, that is because the loading/writing is actually done by `TIdMessageClient`, which has no concept of streams or really any concept of any source/destination other than POP3/SMTP.  It is a hard-coded limitation in Indy's current architecture that will be addressed in Indy 11.  In the meantime, there are workarounds using the `TIdIOHandlerStreamMsg` class.

Try this:

```
IdMsg->ExtraHeaders->Values["Bcc"] = EncodeAddress(IdMsg->BCCList, 'B', "utf-8");
boost::scoped_ptr<TIdMessageClient> msgClient(new TIdMessageClient(NULL));
boost::scoped_ptr<TIdIOHandlerStreamMsg> io(new TIdIOHandlerStreamMsg(NULL, NULL, Target Stream Goes Here);
io->UnescapeLines = true; // <-- this is the key step!
io->FreeStreams = false;
msgClient->IOHandler = io.get();
msgClient->SendMsg(IdMsg, false);
```

```
IdMsg->Clear();
boost::scoped_ptr<TIdMessageClient> msgClient(new TIdMessageClient(NULL));
boost::scoped_ptr<TIdIOHandlerStreamMsg> io(new TIdIOHandlerStreamMsg(NULL, Source Stream Goes Here, NULL);
io->EscapeLines = true; // <-- this is the key step!
io->FreeStreams = false;
msgClient->IOHandler = io.get();
io->Open();
msgClient->ProcessMessage(IdMsg, false);
```

`UnescapeLines=true` causes `TIdIOHandlerStreamMsg` to silently undo the extra data that `TIdMessageClient` writes when saving the `TIdMessage`.

`EscapeLines=true` causes `TIdIOHandlerStreamMsg` to add extra data that `TIdMessageClient` is expecting to parse when loading a `TIdMessage`.

Comment: I understand that this is a workaround. But how about making the above into built-in function?

Comment: Because it would require interface changes I'm not ready to make yet.

Comment: Just an FYI, I did end up creating a separate `class helper` for `TIdMessage` to add overloaded `LoadFrom...()` and `SaveTo...()` methods for dealing with the dot-transparency issue, but it has not been checked in yet.